# Which web browsers support the MPEG-DASH streaming protocol?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, video-streaming, media-source

I have found something bellow:

According to: [This Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2014/01/03/mpeg-dash-tutorial-embedding-an-adaptive-streaming-video-within-your-html5-application.aspx)

> DASH is supported by any browser any browser that supports the 
>   W3C Media Source Extensions (MSE), today that is Chrome and IE11

And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video)

> Firefox 21 includes an implementation of DASH for HTML5 WebM video which is turned off 
>   by  default. It can be enabled via "`about:config`" and the "media.dash.enabled" preference.
>   Firefox 23 removed support for DASH for HTML5 WebM video

But I can only made it run in Chrome(23+). Could you tell me all browsers that support **DASH MPEG** for streaming video?

Comment: MPEG-DASH is still very new. Could you please tell what source stream you're having difficulties with?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Browsers do not support MPEG-DASH natively

Websites need JavaScript libraries to play DASH streaming. These open source MPEG-DASH player libraries require [MSE](http://w3c.github.io/media-source/) support in the browser:

- [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js): official reference implementation
- [Shaka Player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player): Google's player library

Other clients:

- [dashas](https://github.com/castlabs/dashas): open source client written in Flash (so no MSE support needed)
- [commercial clients](http://dashif.org/clients/)

### MSE Support in Browsers

- **Chrome 23**
- **IE 11** (only on Windows 8+)
- **Edge**
- **Safari 8.0** (only on OS X, not on iOS)
- **Firefox 42**
- Opera 20, only WebM, no h.264 yet (as of 26)

Also, the HLS implementation in Safari 10 (both iOS and Mac) now supports MPEG-DASH mp4 fragments, which means you don't need to generate your media fragments twice to support HLS and MPEG-DASH. You only need two types of manifest files.

You can try out the official [MPEG-DASH test vectors](http://dashif.org/test-vectors/) in your own browser.

More MSE browser support information: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=mse), [JW Player](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/mediasource/), [HTML5test](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/video-mediasource.html)

Comment: Thank you, I had use dash.js and successfully make it run on Firefox 21, IE11 and Chrome 23. I'll check Opera later.Live video is still difficult!!!

Comment: As of Firefox 42, MSE is now available and therefore DASH+mp4 is now supported natively on it

Comment: Link to test vectors is dead. (I suppose it is now https://testassets.dashif.org/; some explanation about what that is and its purpose would be nice to have.)

Answer (score 5):

Browser support for MPEG-DASH is indeed mainly based on the [MSE - Media Source Extensions specification](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) as of today. It can be used in combination with an HTML5 video tag to playback MPEG-DASH stream within a browser. Plus there are some codecs consideration to take on board. A list of browsers that can support MPEG-DASH with the MSE extension follows:

- Chrome 23+: DASH264 and WebM Dash
- IE 11 on Windows 8+: DASH264
- MS Edge: DASH264
- Opera 20+: WebM Dash. Opera 30+ also support DASH264.
- Safari 8+ on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10): DASH264 ... that seemed to be broken during my testing
- Chrome 34+ on Android 4.2+: DASH264 and WebM Dash
- Firefox 42+: DASH264 (WebM Dash seems to be coming)

No support:

- iOS 8 Safari does **not** provide support

[Radiant Media Player](https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com) (disclaimer: I am the founder) supports MPEG-DASH (DASH264) for on-demand and live video streaming in HTML5 with various fallback options.

Note: MPEG-DASH is not as such a streaming protocol, it is a container format like MPEG-4 (ie the MPEG in MPEG-DASH) the delivery protocol being HTTP

Answer (score 1):

There is the bitdash MPEG-DASH player which works on any web browser:

- IE11 (Windows 8) and Chrome use the HTML5 (MSE) + JavaScript based implementation.
- All other browsers (which do not support the HTML5 Media Source Extentions) get a Flash-based MPEG-DASH player.

On top of that comes a unified API, so if someone uses bitdash s/he has not to pay attention weather the HTML5 or the Flash version is used.

A free version is avalable on http://dash-player.com

Comment: iOS has no MSE and no Flash, but this player *does* seem to work on iOS 8. But how?

Comment: After reading the docs it seems the player has a HLS fallback option.

Comment: yes, the player has a fallback option to HLS as well as progressive download

Answer (score 0):

MPEG DASH is a streaming protocol and strives to be agnostic in regards of the audio and video codecs. For example it may carry video encoded using H.264, HEVC, VP8 or VP9 codecs.

Whether a browser is capable of playing back different content depends on the codecs it supports, not its MPEG DASH compatibility.

For Firefox, you can see the list of supported codecs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Regarding MPEG DASH protocol specific compatibility, there is an Open Source reference player that perhaps you want to try: [DASH.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js)